# sqlite group by update where max

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to do a update on a SQLite table, to set a column value to 1 only if that row has the max value of a particular column in that grouping.

Ex:
Grouping by BookID, set Latest=1 only when BookVersion is max.

```
BookID BookVersion 
==================
ABC      1
ABC      2
ABC      3
DEF      1

Output
BookID BookVersion Latest
==========================
ABC        1         0
ABC        2         0
ABC        3         1
DEF        1         1
```

I tried

```
update Books set Latest=1 from Books INNER JOIN (select BookId, MAX(BookVersion) from Books GROUP BY BookId );
```

I receive:

`SQL error: near "from": syntax error`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite doesn't support `update` with `join`.  You can do the same thing with a `where` clause, I think:

```
update Books
    set Latest = 1 
    where not exists (select 1
                      from books b2
                      where b2.bookid = Books.bookid and
                            b2.bookversion > Books.bookversion
                     );
```

The logic here is "Update the rows where the bookid has no larger version number."

Comment: Thanks. That works. What does "select 1" mean though - unfamiliar with that

Comment: @excalibur . . . The `not exists` is just looking for any record returned by the subquery.  The `1` is a very simple value, although anything can really go there (I do recommend avoiding `NULL` because it is confusing to think of `NULL` as representing a valid value).